# Correct spelling in ajax POST

Tags: ajax

I have two verions of code I believe should do the same thing, but the first one works and other one doesn't (Post vars: agenti, week_, team_). I have searched for few examples of how to do it the other way and I am sure my example is similar.
What do I do wrong?

First:

```
$.post("index.html",
{
  agenti: getItems(),
  week_: week_array,
  team_: team
},
function(data,status){
  if (status = 'Success'){
    alert('Aktuální řazení operátorů bylo úspěšně uloženo.');
  } else {
    alert('Aktuální řazení operátorů se nepodařilo uložit.\nKontaktujte prosím správce aplikace.');
  }
```

Second:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "index.html",
    data: JSON.stringify({agenti: getItems(), week_: week_array, team_: team}),
    success: function (msg)
    {
        alert('Aktuální řazení operátorů bylo úspěšně uloženo.')
    },
    error: function (msg)
    {
        alert('Aktuální řazení operátorů se nepodařilo uložit.\nKontaktujte prosím správce aplikace.')
    } 
  });
```

I want to do the second one because I need to specify content type and i couldn't figure how to do it in the first way.
Thanks you!

edit: I use IE; this code will be used only in IE.

Comment: Ok I managed to deal with the encoding problem using iconv, so I stayed with the .post method. Still it bothers my why the other way doesn't work?

Comment: posting to html page! really?

Answer (score 0):

so the first thing is that, no need to use `JSON.stringify` function, as the `data` accepts JSON objects, as well the string represented like a url (test1=1&test2=2...). So to use it like  the following is ok.

```
data: {agenti: getItems(), week_: week_array, team_: team},
```

Also when you are using `contentType`: 'application/json' the GLOBAL $_POST variable is not being populated as it is being populated only for `form-urlencoded` data which is default value for `contentType` option, here you go with data from jQuery reference`

```
contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
```

In order you like to use `application/json`, you can retrieve that information in PHP side using php input like this following. `file_get_contents('php://input');`

---Working Example---

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost",
    data: {agenti: 'test1', week_: 'test2', team_: 'test3'},
    success: function(msg) {},
    error: function(msg) {}
});
```

PHP:

```
// Retrieve the input
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
// Use $_POST var
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Comment: I already tried to edit the data part as you suggest and it didn't work. I also tried to delete the contentType part at all and also didn't help.

Comment: Try to edit the data part as I have suggested, also comment the contentType option, and check. It works for me.

Comment: Tried, doesn't work. Also all the other scripts on page stop working when I add this one. I have checked many times and there shouldn't be any problem with brackets or similar stuff.

Comment: I have edited my answer and put some ---Working Example--- there, you can check it out. It might be useful. In order to see what goes back from server side, I have used browser network tool. (in order it might be needed)

Comment: Good idea to see the output! Now it outputs (into PHP): string(22) "razeni_ulozit=Uložit"; where "razeni_ulozit" is ID of the button I call the function upon pressing, and "Uložit" is the value of it.

Comment: Also occurred to me that might be important - agenti is array built using javascript, week_ is array I get from php using json and team is var from php I also get with json.

Comment: Check out serialize(https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and serializeArray(https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) jQuery functions, which allows convert js data to string, it might be helpful.